# Error in if (any(co)) { : valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario

Tags: r, rstudio

He estado entrenando algunos modelos y cuando intento usar Support Vector Machines con Radial Basis Function Kernel me sale el siguiente error:

```
    Error in if (any(co)) { : valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
Además: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introducidos por coerción
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introducidos por coerción
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introducidos por coerción
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introducidos por coerción
5: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introducidos por coerción
Called from: .local(x, ...)
Browse[1]>
```

Aquí un resumen de mi base de datos:

```
summary(Fraud_trainX)
        Make      AccidentArea                PolicyType   VehicleCategory
 Pontiac  :1427   Rural: 576   SedC                :2059   Sedan  :3557   
 Toyota   :1188   Urban:5081   SedL                :1828   Sport  :1958   
 Honda    : 987                SedA                :1498   Utility: 142   
 Mazda    : 801                SpoC                : 126                  
 Chevrolet: 630                Utility - All Perils: 124                  
 Accura   : 196                UtiCL               :  18                  
 (Other)  : 428                (Other)             :   4                  
 BasePolicy WeekOfMonthClaimed      Age       RepNumber        Deductible   
 AP:1625    Min.   :1.000      Min.   :16   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :300.0  
 C :2196    1st Qu.:2.000      1st Qu.:31   1st Qu.: 4.000   1st Qu.:400.0  
 L :1836    Median :3.000      Median :39   Median : 8.000   Median :400.0  
            Mean   :2.706      Mean   :41   Mean   : 8.434   Mean   :408.2  
            3rd Qu.:4.000      3rd Qu.:49   3rd Qu.:12.000   3rd Qu.:400.0  
            Max.   :5.000      Max.   :80   Max.   :16.000   Max.   :700.0  
                                                                            
  DriverRating        Year        ClaimSize          Month         WeekOfMonth   
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1994   Min.   :     0   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:1994   1st Qu.:  4156   1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median :3.000   Median :1995   Median :  8059   Median : 6.000   Median :3.000  
 Mean   :2.495   Mean   :1995   Mean   : 22437   Mean   : 6.462   Mean   :2.789  
 3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:1996   3rd Qu.: 38028   3rd Qu.:10.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
 Max.   :4.000   Max.   :1996   Max.   :141394   Max.   :12.000   Max.   :5.000  
                                                                                 
   DayOfWeek     DayOfWeekClaimed  MonthClaimed         Sex        
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000    Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:2.000    1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.:1.0000  
 Median :4.000   Median :3.000    Median : 6.000   Median :1.0000  
 Mean   :3.812   Mean   :2.828    Mean   : 6.445   Mean   :0.8414  
 3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:4.000    3rd Qu.:10.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
 Max.   :7.000   Max.   :7.000    Max.   :12.000   Max.   :1.0000  
                                                                   
 MaritalStatus       Fault         VehiclePrice   Days_Policy_Accident
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.000       
 1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:4.000       
 Median :2.000   Median :0.0000   Median :2.000   Median :4.000       
 Mean   :1.719   Mean   :0.2744   Mean   :2.727   Mean   :3.977       
 3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:4.000       
 Max.   :3.000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :6.000   Max.   :4.000       
                                                                      
 Days_Policy_Claim PastNumberOfClaims  AgeOfVehicle   AgeOfPolicyHolder
 Min.   :1.000     Min.   :0.000      Min.   :0.000   Min.   :2.000    
 1st Qu.:3.000     1st Qu.:0.000      1st Qu.:6.000   1st Qu.:5.000    
 Median :3.000     Median :1.000      Median :7.000   Median :6.000    
 Mean   :2.994     Mean   :1.364      Mean   :6.748   Mean   :6.028    
 3rd Qu.:3.000     3rd Qu.:2.000      3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:7.000    
 Max.   :3.000     Max.   :3.000      Max.   :8.000   Max.   :9.000    
                                                                       
 PoliceReportFiled WitnessPresent       AgentType       NumberOfSuppliments
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.000      
 1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.000      
 Median :0.00000   Median :0.000000   Median :0.00000   Median :1.000      
 Mean   :0.02846   Mean   :0.005126   Mean   :0.01467   Mean   :1.197      
 3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:3.000      
 Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :3.000      
                                                                           
 AddressChange_Claim  NumberOfCars   
 Min.   :0.0000      Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000      1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.0000      Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.1801      Mean   :0.1027  
 3rd Qu.:0.0000      3rd Qu.:0.0000  
 Max.   :3.0000      Max.   :3.0000
```

La estructura de la base de datos:

```
str(Fraud_trainX)
'data.frame':   5657 obs. of  32 variables:
 $ Make                : Factor w/ 19 levels "Accura","BMW",..: 7 7 10 7 6 6 6 3 3 14 ...
 $ AccidentArea        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Rural","Urban": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ PolicyType          : Factor w/ 8 levels "SedA","SedC",..: 4 5 1 3 3 3 1 2 2 3 ...
 $ VehicleCategory     : Factor w/ 3 levels "Sedan","Sport",..: 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ BasePolicy          : Factor w/ 3 levels "AP","C","L": 3 2 1 3 3 3 1 2 2 3 ...
 $ WeekOfMonthClaimed  : num  1 4 3 5 3 5 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Age                 : num  21 34 71 52 28 38 41 28 47 60 ...
 $ RepNumber           : num  12 15 7 13 11 16 15 6 13 16 ...
 $ Deductible          : num  300 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 ...
 $ DriverRating        : num  1 4 3 1 1 1 4 1 2 4 ...
 $ Year                : num  1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 ...
 $ ClaimSize           : num  55526 59294 62624 103421 59748 ...
 $ Month               : int  12 1 3 3 1 8 4 7 1 3 ...
 $ WeekOfMonth         : int  5 3 2 5 3 4 4 5 2 3 ...
 $ DayOfWeek           : int  3 3 7 1 5 2 4 7 6 1 ...
 $ DayOfWeekClaimed    : int  2 1 3 1 5 1 3 3 1 2 ...
 $ MonthClaimed        : int  1 1 3 3 1 8 5 8 1 4 ...
 $ Sex                 : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ MaritalStatus       : int  1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Fault               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ VehiclePrice        : int  6 6 6 2 6 6 6 2 2 2 ...
 $ Days_Policy_Accident: int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Days_Policy_Claim   : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ PastNumberOfClaims  : int  0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 3 ...
 $ AgeOfVehicle        : int  3 6 8 8 7 6 7 7 8 8 ...
 $ AgeOfPolicyHolder   : int  4 5 9 7 5 6 6 5 7 8 ...
 $ PoliceReportFiled   : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WitnessPresent      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AgentType           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NumberOfSuppliments : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ AddressChange_Claim : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ NumberOfCars        : int  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
```

La variable respuesta:

```
summary(Fraud_trainY)
  No   Si 
5328  329
```

Y aquí un poco sobre el índice y control que uso para el entrenamiento del modelo:

```
indx <- createMultiFolds(Fraud_trainY, k = 5, times = 2)
str(indx)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",index = indx, 
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     sampling = "up",
                     classProbs = TRUE)
```

Y aquí los parámetros del modelo:

```
svmRFit <- train(x = Fraud_trainX, 
                 y = Fraud_trainY, 
                 method = "svmRadial",
                 metric = "ROC",
                 preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                 tuneLength = 15,
                 trControl = ctrl)
```

Ya he intentado cargar la libreria pROC y no me ha dado ningún resultado favorable, ya eliminé los renglones que contenian NA de todas las variables, la variable respuesta ya tiene los niveles "No" y "Si". He hecho este entrenamiento también para C5.0 ("C5.0"), Redes Neuronales (nnet) y Regresión Logística ("multinom") y en todos me han servido los datos y me da el resultado del modelo, este el único modelo que me marca algún tipo de error.

Comment: Hola Moisés Aarón, bienvenido. ¿Revisaste https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027510/error-in-if-anyco-missing-value-where-true-false-needed? Lamentablemente está en inglés. Al parecer esa función tiene  problemas cuando pasas más de un factor como predictor.

Comment: Hola, no lo había revisado pero no me ha funcionado la respuesta, muchas gracias por la información.